# ActiveRecord - how to do includes after the query was executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a scenario with 1->N->N assocations. For example: Post->Comments->Votes (votes will be list of names of people who voted on the comment). To display a page the query with includes might look like:

```
@post = Post.where(:id => 100).includes({:comments => :votes}).first
```

I am starting to add caching support. Which means if the comments partial is already cached I will not need to run include the comments/votes all the time. So I wonder if there is a way to make the code appear like:

```
# controller
@post = Post.find(100)

# view
<% cache('comments', @post.last_comment_time do %>
    <% @post.includes({:comments => :votes}).comments.each do |comment| # ???? %>
<% end %>
```

Running the "post-query" includes, will "fill in" the associations. So @post.comments will be populated and each comment will include all the votes. Is there a way to achieve this?

P.S. I am aware the view is not the best place to run the query, this is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in latest releases of rails, all the finder-methods return a proxy object, that will only trigger a database-call once you send it some iterator-method like `all` or `first` in your case. this is why you can chain all the calls like `Post.where.order.sort.bla`.

it's not possible though to load the post model and use an `includes` call later. `includes` works by using a `join` call on the relations that get loaded with the model instance, so that you have just one database-call instead of one for each relation.

executing active_record code in your view is also a bad practice. the data-retrieval is the responsibility of the controller, not the view.

Comment: I added an edit that the query in the view is only an example. Also for 1->N , includes uses another select. So technically it is possible to add a function to ActiveRecord that performs the additional select and fills the associations. But thanks for confirming this does not yet exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly old question but this *can* be done now like this

```
# controller
@post = Post.find(100)

# view
<% cache('comments', @post.last_comment_time do %>
    <% ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload @post, comments: :votes # this will trigger one query %>
    <% @post.comments.each do |comment| # this will not trigger any additional queries %>
<% end %>
```

Not the cleanest way but it does the job